# HashMap data is deleted unexpectedly

Tags: java, json, collections, hashmap

I'm creating a HashMap as follows:

```
private HashMap <String, JSONArray> HiveMap;
HiveMap = new HashMap <String, JSONArray>();
```

and also a private class variable to store some calculated data which will be put into the HashMap after the calculations are done:

```
private JSONArray hiveList;
```

After hiveList is calculated, I put the hiveList into the created HashMap (HiveMap):

```
HiveMap.put(hiveNode,hiveList);
```

When I print out HiveMap now, the output I get is as expected, with both the fields `hiveNode` and `hiveList` existing in the Hashmap. `<"hiveNode":"hiveList">`

After this is done, I assume that the data I put into the HashMap from `hiveList` is going to persist, so I clear the hiveList array using `hiveList.clear();`

But when I print the Hashmap after clearing hiveList, I see that the data from hiveList is gone from the HashMap as well.

Printing the HashMap after clearing hiveList results in: `<"hiveNode": >`

I don't understand this behavior, I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: `HiveMap = new H..` Where is the identifier?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a _"passing-by-value-of-reference"_ problem.

Comment: @Keyser I don't think so. They are valid lines. If you look carefully, `HiveMap` is the identifier.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes that could very well be the case, but then there's the problem of naming conventions.

Comment: If it is so, then it's an identifier against conventions, and that's wrong just the same.

Comment: @MightyPort. Yeah it does violates the naming convention. But it's not wrong. That's just not best practice. There's a difference.

Comment: @Keyser. Yeah, I would consider it a major issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you helped me figure out where I was going wrong!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is this:

> After this is done, I assume that the data I put into the HashMap from hiveList is going to persist, so I clear the hiveList array using hiveList.clear();

What got passed to the hash map is the reference to the list, not a copy of it.

The most simple fix is to create a new instance instead of clearing it. Alternatively you can make a copy, and put that in the map.

Comment: [Here's an explaination of pass by value](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html)

Comment: Pass by value, of course like always, but the passed value is a reference :-)

Comment: As all objects in Java are, of course. What I meant was that link describes both. Got in too big a hurry.

Answer (score 3):

The `hiveList` list and the list that resides as a value in the `Map` are one and the same, both the variable and the `Map` are holding *references* to the same object; if you `clear()` one list, the other is also emptied - there's a single list, not two.

If you *have to* clear and reuse `hiveList` for some reason (and I don't see why), then you'll need to put a different list in the `Map`, here's how to do a shallow copy:

```
HiveMap.put(hiveNode, new ArrayList<Hive>(hiveList));
```

Replace `<Hive>` with the actual type of the elements in the list.

Answer (score 3):

In java objects are passed by copy of reference and not copy of object. So if you modify the object using reference at one place it get affected at all the places where this object is referred. In you case `hiveList.clear();`
is causing to remove all the elements of the list which is also referred at `HiveMap.put(hiveNode,hiveList);`and hence is eventually removed from the map.

Answer (score 2):

That's how java manages the Object. What you have is the reference to that object and you only  stored a reference to it. So, if you clear the object after storing it in the hashmap, the object from hashmap would also be cleared.

When you create an object java stores the reference along with the object at the same location in the memory. Hence, there's only one reference to that object. So, the result was expected

```
//Stores the reference to the object
HiveMap.put(hiveNode,hiveList);

//Modifies the same object in the memory
hiveList.clear();
```

You may want to read about [Pass by reference and Pass by Value](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html)